# Why MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[] { uri_path_or_subfolder }, null,... ) was not deprecated in AndroidQ,R (SDK29,30)?

Tags: android-10.0

Why  `MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[] { uri_path_or_subfolder }, null,... )` was not `deprecated` in AndroidQ,R (SDK29,30)?

I have made a small photo stored in `Pictures/subfolderABC` with

```
final Uri contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri("external");
Uri uri = resolver.insert(contentUri, contentValues);
//Then ... Do some works on the uri with bitmap , ParcelFileDescriptor and FileOutputStream
```

I confirmed that uri is not null by checking `uri.toString();`

`System.out.println(uri.toString());`

Debug Dialogue show:
`content://media/external/images/media/85`

In Android SDK<=28, I will usually use

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
     new String[] { file.toString()}, null,
     new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                                public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri_local) {
                                    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                                    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri_local);
                                }
                            });
```

to let the user can find the image created quickly when user open the gallery and no need to wait.

So I attempt to do so in Android Q and R , (SDK 29,30) with similar ways...

```
String testingString;
switch (testingCaseNum){

    case 1: testingString = contentUri.toString(); break; //testing1
    case 2: testingString = uri.toString(); break; //testing2
    case 3: testingString = "content://media/external/images/media"; break; //testing3, should be same as 
    case 4: testingString = relativePath; break; //testing4 //relativePath = "Pictures/subfolderABC"
    case 5: testingString = "Pictures"; break; //testing5

    default:testingString = contentUri.toString(); break;
}

String testingString = contentUri.toString(); //testing
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
     new String[] {tesingString}, null,
     new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
         public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri_local) {
             Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
             Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri_local);
         }
     });
```

The debug dialogue shows:

```
D/MediaScannerConnection: Scanned xxxx to null
I/ExternalStorage: Scanned xxxx:
I/ExternalStorage: -> uri=null
```

I used about 12-18 hours to find the problem why the emulator return a null uri but at the upper codes the image has a uri with id generated! I supposed that I input a wrong String for telling AndroidQ where to scan. But in 1 hour before, I find an eassy summarizing some problems Android Q in 2019 by a developer. He said that all String paths you enter will return null if you put uri!!!!!!
Android Studio didn't pump any hint or message telling me `MediaScannerConnection.scanFile` is not working or deprecated in AndroidQ in Oct 2020 ???? This wastes my time, do Android Studio really know there is problem about scanFile?